# Best way to implement a GMail like notifier in Android

Tags: android, notifications, gmail

I'm looking to make a notifier type app for Android. Just sits in the background and performs a lookup via Internet every so often, and notifies of important incoming data.

Whats the best way to do something like this? How can I make it run only at selected intervals, so as to be battery friendly?

The Gmail notifications in Android seem to check the email as soon as I connect to the Internet. Is there a way for my code to do the same?

Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823185/creating-an-android-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right off the bat, I should mention that the technique you describe in your question is called *polling*. The thing with polling is that isn't very battery/resource friendly and you usually want to stay away from it as much as possible (in the mobile realm).

Now given the description of your problem, what you want to look into is a *push* solution. That's how the Android's Gmail client works. Android's native push solution is called [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) and it's freely available for versions 2.1+.

**Now how would this work?**

The general idea would be this: Using *Gmail* as the example, say the server (i.e. your backend) receives a new email for user `X`. Your server will then send a targeted message to your app installed on `X`'s device at which point your app will contact your server and retrieve the message.

**Now let me briefly describe polling:**

```
App: Hey, got anything for me?
Server: Nope
App: sleep for a bit
App: Hey, got anything for me?
Server: Nope
App: sleep for a bit
App: Hey, got anything for me?
Server: Yep, here it is!
...
```

In the latter example, your app consumed all those extra resources without actually accomplishing anything whereas in the push scenario, it was *one* call to the server to retrieve the message. You can easily see how *bad* polling can be on battery life.

Comment: Awesome, however I don't own the server which would be queried, so I can't get a targeted message. I would query via XML API. Is polling the only way to go in this case? Is sleep() ing an option?

Comment: @Rob If you have _absolutely_ no control over the server, it looks like polling will be your only option. In this scenario, consider limiting the time window in which your app checks the server. For example, only _start_ polling when they launch the app and immediately kill it when they exit. If you _have_ to keep it running all the time, you'll probably have to implement a background service that periodically makes the XML calls - but I highly advise against this! Battery usage will be abysmal and your app ratings (if you publish it in the Android Market) _will_ reflect this.

Comment: +1 for reference to c2dm. are there any non-google push alternatives?

Comment: Yeah, I have absolutely no control over the server. Is there anything like cron for Android apps? A notifier is no good if you have to run it manually. Thanks!

Comment: @k3b Two alternatives to C2DM are [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/) and [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/). I'm considering PubNub for an upcoming project of mine just because of their free quota but UA is pretty decent as well. Note that both these solutions are _cross platform_ and also should theoretically work on _any_ version of Android (i.e. pre 2.1 as well).

Comment: @Rob Then yes, you want to look into implementing a [background service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) that brings up your (frontend) app whenever something new arrives. That link should be a pretty good resource to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

There is application named Goofier. It does exactly what you ask and can server more than one gmail account. It is packaged as web application and runs on Android under TJWS. Any other app server can be used though and the app can be extracted and make run as standalone.

Answer (score 0):

@Rob AlarmManager is the Android cron alternative.